# Is there a clear and correct reference for full icosahedral symmetry that includes a presentation and its action on vertices, edges, and faces?

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, solid-geometry

> Is there a clear and correct reference for full icosahedral symmetry that includes a presentation and its action on vertices, edges, and faces?

The [Wikipedia article for icoshedral symmetry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry) gives the [following presentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry#As_point_group) for the full icosahedral group:

$$I_h:  \langle s,t\mid s^3(st)^{-2}, t^5(st)^{-2}\rangle$$

This of course is the presentation for $\operatorname{SL}(2,5)$ as it is a 2-fold covering of the 2-3-5 group $\langle s,t \mid (st)^2 = s^3 = t^5 = 1\rangle$. However, the article is [quite clear about this being the wrong group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedral_symmetry#Commonly_confused_groups).

This confusion has been in the article since [Jan 2006](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Icosahedral_symmetry&diff=36065388&oldid=26173380).

Comment: The action is important since there have also been numerous errors related to this in the article, but I think none survive in the current version.

Comment: This is just a whim, but have you tried Magnus' book on tesselations?

Comment: Magnus's book has a nice picture, but his treatment of $I_h$ is less explicit than of $I$ (he does give the Coxeter presentation). Unfortunately he also gives the presentation of SL(2,5) as thinks of A5s rep on the icosahedron as a projective rep on the plane, and projective reps are described in terms of covers. This happens in a few books (Hatcher is another). No incorrect statements in the books, but the three nonsolvable groups of order 120 are all mentioned in one paragraph without clearly distinguishing them or recognizing the potential for confusion.

Comment: Hmm. Then my other whim is Coxeter-Moser's book. There won't be a picture, but there might be a presentation. Other than that, I am out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: Few days before, I had over-read in the book "Finite Reflection Groups"-Grove, Benson that the full symmetry group has order 120.

Comment: A classical book: Felix Klein, *Lectures on the Icosahedron and the Solution of Equations of the Fifth Degree*

Comment: I don't know much about presentations so this may be dumb, but since $I_h=I \times Z_2$ isn't using the presentation for $I$ and adding rules for $(e, 1)$ enough? Or do you need it to just use two letters?